# how to fetch a element from a string

Tags: python-3.x

I want to get the specific from a string like I have a string:
   Hardware is FAS-2030-2T+
Note the spaces in the starting of string
I want to retrieve FAS-2030-2T+
should I use re.search or re.match
if so how?
Please help me I got stuck some where and new to python

thanks in advance

-P

Comment: if(re.match('.*Hardware is.*',list)):
        #print ("Befroe List is ::",list)
        list1=shlex.split(list)
        #print ("List is ::",list1)
        print ("The Hardware is ::",list1[2])

Answer (score 0):

```
if(re.match('.*Hardware is.*',list)):
    #print ("Befroe List is ::",list)
    list1=shlex.split(list)
    #print ("List is ::",list1)
    print ("The Hardware is ::",list1[2])
```